# PHP array - how to format output like this?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, format

**Array:**

```
Array(
    [4:3] =>Array(
        [0] => 800x600
        [1] => 1024x768
        [2] => 1600x1200
        [3] => 2048x1536
    )
    [16:9] => Array(
        [0] => 1366x768
        [1] => 1920x1080
    )
    [Apple] => Array(
        [iPad2] => 1024x768
        [iPad3] => 2048x1536
    )
)
```

**How formatted output should look:**

```
<p>4:3</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="800x600.jpg">800x600</a></li>
  <li><a href="1024x768.jpg">1024x768</a></li>
  <li><a href="1600x1200.jpg">1600x1200</a></li>
  <li><a href="2048x1536.jpg">2048x1536</a></li>
</ul>
<p>16:9</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="1366x768.jpg">1366x768</a></li>
  <li><a href="1920x1080.jpg">1920x1080</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Apple</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="1024x768.jpg">iPad2</a></li>
  <li><a href="2048x1536.jpg">iPad3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Problem:**
I can iterate through array, but I have no idea how can I get output as shown above.

Comment: This looks like something you could do with two loops; what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
     echo '<p>'. $key .'</p>';
     echo '<ul>';
     foreach ($row as $v) {
         echo '<li><a href="' . $v . '.jpg">' .  $v . '</a></li>';
     }         
     echo '</ul>';

}
```

Comment: Its not what i wanted but it gave me idea :)

Answer (score 0):

use echo "" and concate it with array values.using . operator